# Accessing Python Command Line Script Objects

Tags: scripting, command-line

If I generate an object in a python script e.g. called draw_a_cube.py

`def my_mesh_func(*kwargs):`

`return useful_mesh`

`pycube = bpy.data.objects.new("myCube", my_mesh_func(*vars))`

`... blah blah`

Then I run that python script on the command line:

`blender --python draw_a_cube.py`

Can I access the pycube object / my_mesh_func in the python interactive console in blender?

I'm talking 2.8+ btw!

Thanks,

a